# 2 failed questions and im banned from new ones !!! and im not even asking questions but sharing my solutions?

Tags: support

The first is irrepairable, it just should not have been asked here i agree, the second i have correct.

Ive read about hidden deleted questions, where are they ?

Is this site too harsh ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: as far as i can tell i dont have any deleted questions ? I will try improving my open questions...

Comment: You have three deleted questions.

Comment: Where ? how do i find them ?

Comment: You can’t, they are hidden by design.

Comment: So is my account doomed and i should give up ?

Comment: The deleted questions are from 2014 and 2015 so I think they are too old to have any effect now. This sort of automated block arises mostly from recent questions.

Comment: So one bad question, which got closed by you @MichaelHampton, which I go on to edit and make acceptable as best i can and I get banned ? My last question before that was almost a year ago (It did get closed, and I agree it belonged at unix stack where i reposted it, so it is irreparable) and the one before that was 3 years before that ! So you can see how it just seems i am being punished unfairly for foolishly but harmlessly posting the answer to my question in the question section as well ?!

Comment: The [community reviewed your question](https://serverfault.com/review/reopen/397783) after you edited it, and the result was not to reopen it. I'm not inclined to reopen it either, as it has to do with Virtualmin, questions about which are not on topic here anyway. But I will change the close reason for it, so that it is more clear.

Comment: So why have tags for virtualmin ? I edited it several times, and i dont believe it has been reviewed since its latest formating.

Comment: I am one of the people who voted to not reopen the question. My reason was that it was about virtualmin. It had nothing to do with formatting. As to how you should have known that it was on-topic: You could have read https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic before posting. The fact that a tag exists doesn't mean it's on-topic; people can and do create tags without oversight.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting the message:

> “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”

Then you need to read the post you were given a link to.  That is all of the advice anyone can give you.  It means you've asked too many questions which have not been well-received - they've been downvoted and/or closed and/or deleted.

In a comment on your most recent question, you said you were getting a message like:

> "You have reached your question limit"

If that's the message you're getting, you need to read this other post on meta.SE about rate limits:  [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide)

Either way, moderators on this site can't do anything, both of the above are purely automatic systems.  As mentioned in the comments, the deleted questions are very old, so there's likely no point in trying to improve them.

Basically, depending on which message you're actually getting, follow the advice in the linked meta.SE post.  You mention in the title of this post that you're, "not even asking questions but sharing my solutions?"  It's totally fine to post a question and your own answer at the same time, but when you do that, you need to make sure your question is clear and relevant.

Comment: It says both "You have reached your question limit & Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. " the links to a page saying it is a ban, nothing about rate limiting https://serverfault.com/help/question-bans if you look at my account yo can see it doesnt look that bad does it ? Just because i asked some unique questions i should not be punished, i have nothing in the negative. and many of my questions are old and have little chance of being up voted even if i do edit them because they have been superseded most likely by software updates & changes.

Comment: If you're getting the "we are no longer accepting questions..." message, then the automatic system that is in place on all SE sites has determined that your questions have not, overall, been very good.  Looking at your list, you have no questions with net upvotes - they're all 0 or -ive.  One way to get out of the question ban is to improve your existing questions.  I have no suggestions on how to do that.  I think that providing some good answers can also help lif the ban.  The final resort is that you can post one question every 6 months - if it comes to that, make sure it's a good question.